# How to mock a webapi controller that has actions that return Task<IHttpActionResult> using Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I am trying to refactor an Asp.Net MVC Single-Page app. WebApi used to be the service layer but due to some issues with authentication I had to change it to  a direct reference. The WebApi project has the UnitTests but the MVC app doesn't.

I am struggling to mock [using Moq] the `Task<IHttpActionResult>` types the WebApi returns.

My ApiController looks like this:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(MyModel myModel)
{
     .......
     return Ok(result);
}
```

and in my MVC controller I am using this inside an action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post(MyViewModel myViewModel)
{
    ...
    ....
    var resultFromApiController = await myApiController.Post(myViewModel.model);
    ....
}
```

How do I test Post Action of the MVC controller?

Comment: Did the suggestion of .ReturnsAsync<> work?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your APIs name is FooApi and the Controller you are testing is called FooController your UnitTest could look something similar like this this:

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod()
{
    // Arrange
    var apiMock = new Mock<IFooApi>();
    apiMock.Setup(api => api.Post(It.IsAny<MyModel>())).ReturnsAsync(new OkNegotiatedContentResult<Result>(new Result(), new FooApi()));

    // Act
    var testObject = new FooController(apiMock.Object);
    var viewResult = testObject.Post(new MyViewModel()).Result as ViewResult;
    var result = (Result)viewResult.Model;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(2, result.Product);
}
```

The Object `Result` represents the typ of your ActionResult of your Controller. Eg.:

`return this.View("index", new Result());`